# Will bloody skeleton remain under control after being destroyed?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters, undead

[Animate dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead) allows you to create a bloody skeleton variant instead of a regular skeleton, which has the **Deathless (Su)** ability.

> **Deathless (Su)**
>
> **A bloody skeleton is destroyed when reduced to 0 hit points**, but it returns to unlife 1 hour later at 1 hit point, allowing its fast healing thereafter to resume healing it. A bloody skeleton can be permanently destroyed if it is destroyed by positive energy, if it is reduced to 0 hit points in the area of a bless or hallow spell, or if its remains are sprinkled with a vial of holy water.

Will a destroyed bloody skeleton remain under the necromancer's control when it returns after 1 hour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

Unless they are permanently destroyed, they are not actually being destroyed, and will remain under your control due to this text on [Animate Dead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead):

> The undead you create remain under your control indefinitely.

The spell will simply re-animate them again, under your control once more.

Other forms of control may have a different ruling. But according to [James Jacobs](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2k41s?What-is-the-Command-Undead-Feat-Duration#5) (Creative Director), those controlled by the feat [Command Undead](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/command-undead) are also permanent.